# Dimensional analysis vibration frequency of a star

Tags: classical-mechanics, dimensional-analysis

I'm doing a classical mechanics course of the MIT on my own. In a problem set there is the following problem to be solved using dimensional analysis:
"Derive  an  expression  for  the  vibration  frequency  of  a  star  of  mass M and radius  R,  if  that  vibration  is  caused  by  gravitational  instabilities. "
My problem is that I really don't know with what to start and how to proceed, my page is white. Can you please help me?

Comment: I think you can model it with a linear harmonic oscillator balancing around an equilibric state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f\approx G^aM^bR^c$$
$$\text{s}^{-1}=[\text{kg}^{-1}\text{m}^3\text{s}^{-2}]^a [\text{kg}]^b [\text{m}]^c=\text{kg}^{b-a}\text{m}^{3a+c}\text{s}^{-2a}$$
So
$$a=1/2, b=1/2, c=-3/2$$
$$f\approx \sqrt{\frac{GM}{R^3}}$$

Comment: Please don't answer "blank slate" homework questions.